# Prove that there are at most finitely many numbers $ n$ for which $ p(n)>2^{n+1}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $ p$ be a nonzero polynomial with integral
coefficients，Prove that there are at most finitely many numbers
$ n$ for which $$ p(n)>2^{n+1}$$

WLOG,I think take $p(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\cdots+a_{k}x^k$,then
it is  show that  there are at most finitely many numbers
$ n$ for which $$ a_{0}+a_{1}n+a_{2}n^2+\cdots+a_{k}n^k>2^{n+1}$$
that's why?

Comment: You have just restated the problem.

Comment: Yes, after I replied haha

Comment: That's not wlog... That's just writing out the polynomial in sumation form, that neither helps, hinders, clarifies, nor obfuscates anything.  It just restates the problem.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p(n)}{2^{n+1}}=0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{p(n)}{2^{n+1}}<1$ for all $n\geq N$, or equivalently, $p(n)<2^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq N$.